# C++: Using any iterator type in a faux-STL class?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm creating a container class very similar to a vector (class project), and have defined an iterator subclass. One of the ctors takes two iterator arguments, and builds the data structure (doubly linked list) using the half-open range they represent.

The code below (almost) works for cases when insert(iterator, iterator) is called with two iterators of type Sol::iterator (for some reason, *ita always points to the right values, but the insert(*ita) call doesn't seem to add the value??). The (larger) problem is that the insert call needs to work for all iterator types (ex. vector::iterator), and I haven't been able to track down how to make that work. I've tried typedef / typename T::iterator iterator, but the quietest g++ has been was with 'typename T::iterator iterator', and it returns

```
g++ ex1.cc -o sol -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic
In file included from ex1.cc:1:0:
Sol.h:87:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ita’
ex1.cc:109:5: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
In file included from ex1.cc:1:0:
Sol.h:84:3: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
make: *** [ex1] Error 1
```

which doesn't make much sense; at least to me. Here's the broad strokes:

```
template <class T, int find_val = 1, class Compare = std::less<T> >
class Sol{

public:
    typedef unsigned int size_type; //typedef'ing class variable types
    typedef T key_type; 
    typedef T value_type; 
    //typename T::iterator iter;

private:

    struct node{ //Used as 'links' in the chain that is the doubly linked list
        T data;
        node *prev;
        node *next;
    };

    node *head, *tail; //The head and tail of the dll
    int find_promote_value; //How much should find() shift a value?

public:
    class iterator{
        private:
            node *no;
            friend class Sol;
            iterator(node *p) : no(p){
            }
        public:
            iterator() : no(0){
            }

            iterator operator++(){ //Preincrement
                no = no->next;
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator++(int){ //Postincrement
                iterator temp = *this;
                ++*this;
                return temp;
            }

            iterator operator--(){  //Predecrement
                no = no->prev;
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator--(int){  //Postdecriment
                iterator temp = *this;
                --*this;
                return temp;
            }

            T operator*(){
                return no->data;
            }

            T *operator->(){
                return &no->data;
            }

            bool operator==(const iterator &rhs){
                return no == rhs.no;
            }

            bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs){
                return no != rhs.no;
            }       
    };

    Sol() : head(0), tail(0), find_promote_value(find_val){
    }

    Sol(const Sol &rhs) : head(rhs.head), tail(rhs.tail), find_promote_value(rhs.find_promote_value){
    }

    typename T::iterator iterator;
    Sol(iterator ita, iterator itb){ //Sol.h::87. Problem line
        while (ita != itb){
            iterator itr = insert(*ita);
std::cout << "Inserting " << *ita << ",printout: " << *itr <<"\n";
//dump();
            ++ita;
        }
    }

    ~Sol(){
        clear();
    }

    iterator insert(T input){
        node *n = new node;
        n->next = NULL;
        n->prev = tail;
        n->data = input;

        if(!tail){
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
        }

        return iterator(tail);
    }
   };
```

Comment: No; it's a ctor, so I don't think I need it?

Comment: I am sorry for the noise. I did closely observe that `Sol` is class type.

Comment: No sweat, man; I appreciate having the eyes on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The (larger) problem is that the insert call needs to work for all iterator types (ex. vector::iterator), and I haven't been able to track down how to make that work.

The fact that you need this to work for all iterator types is an indication that it should be a templated function.  If you look at the `insert()` functions provided by the `std::list` container, you'll see that one of them has the following declaration:

```
template <class InputIterator>
void insert(iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Which allows it to use any type for `first` and `last` (which specify the half-open range to insert) as long as that type provides the operations that the `insert()` function uses.  You should consider doing something similar.  As long as your `insert()` function only does the following things to those parameters, you should be able to use pretty much any iterator (except an output iterator):

- compare
- dereference
- increment

Comment: You, sir, win all of my internets. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of the `iterator` class.